# Как мне применить к конкретному but [i] новый класс

Tags: javascript, this

> Здравствуйте. Почему не работает здесь this. Как мне применить к
>   конкретному div (but [i]) новый класс.  Необходимо чтоб при нажатии
>   клавиши клавиатуры (например 1, которая также имеет символ !) клавиша
>   меняла цвет (для этого добавляется новый класс). Каждый div это отдельная клавиша клавиатуры

```
<label for="#inp">
<h2>Введите что нибудь:&nbsp; </h2>
</label><input type="text" id="inp"></div>
<div class='digit'>
<div class="div-1 buttoN"> 1 </div>
<div class="div-2 buttoN"> 2 </div>
<div class="div-3 buttoN"> 3 </div>
<div class="div-4 buttoN"> 4 </div>
<div class="div-5 buttoN"> 5 </div>


 let inp = document.querySelector("#inp"); // Получаю значения из input 
 let but = document.querySelectorAll('.buttoN'); // Получаю множество блоков div  
 inp.onkeydown = function (event) {  
    for (var i = 0; i < but.length; i++) {  
        but[i].textContent == event.code;  
        if (event.code == 'Digit1') {  
            **this.but[i].classList.toggle('colY');**  
            inp.onkeyup = function () {  
                if (event.code == 'Digit1') {  
                    this.but[i].classList.toggle('colY');  
                };  
            }  
            if (event.code == 'Digit2') {  
                this.but[i].classList.toggle('colY');  
                inp.onkeyup = function () {  
                    if (event.code == 'Digit1') {  
                        this.but[i].classList.toggle('colY');  
                    };  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: добавте разметку и обьясните какой должен бить итоговий результат ? потомучто сейчас ви добавляете кучу хендлеров  на кейап инпута и ето странно

Comment: а почему вы решили, что у `this` есть поле `but`, если вы сами создали эту переменную.

Comment: почему в одной строчке вы используете `but[i].textContent` без `this` и вас это не смущает ( а тут доступ к конкретному элементу )

Comment: `this.but[i].classList.toggle('colY');` а тут уже обращаетесь через `this`, можно узнать, как вы рассуждали в этот момент?

Comment: onkeyup тоже должен быть с this. Это я недосмотрел.

Comment: Я то и пытаюсь понять, как можно применить this (если это конечно возможно) чтоб оптимизировать код.

Comment: @AleksandrM Следует объяснить словами, что должен делать этот код. Потому что понять это - невозможно.

Comment: <label for="#inp">
<h2>Введите что нибудь:&nbsp; </h2>
</label><input type="text" id="inp"></div>
<div class='digit'>
<div class="div-1 buttoN"> 1 </div>
<div class="div-2 buttoN"> 2 </div>
<div class="div-3 buttoN"> 3 </div>
<div class="div-4 buttoN"> 4 </div>
<div class="div-5 buttoN"> 5 </div>

Comment: Необходимо чтоб при нажатии клавиши клавиатуры (например 1, которая также имеет символ !) клавиша меняла цвет (для этого добавляется новый класс)

Comment: Каждый div это отдельная клавиша клавиатуры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let inp = document.querySelector("#inp");
let digit = document.querySelector(".digit");

inp.onkeydown = function(event) {
  console.log(event.key);
  var b = digit.querySelector(".div-" + event.key);
  if (b)
    b.classList.toggle("colY");
};
```

```css
.colY {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="#inp">
<h2>Введите что-нибудь:&nbsp; </h2>
</label>
<input type="text" id="inp"></div>
<div class='digit'>
  <div class="div-1 buttoN"> 1 </div>
  <div class="div-2 buttoN"> 2 </div>
  <div class="div-3 buttoN"> 3 </div>
  <div class="div-4 buttoN"> 4 </div>
  <div class="div-5 buttoN"> 5 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное Igor. Все работает.